# Haskell: how to view command history inside "Prelude"?

Tags: haskell, command, history, haskell-prelude

Hello: I wish to list all historical command in Prelude, in the way that any unix shell could in "history" command. I tried several guesses but failed. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean in GHCi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mine appears at ~/.ghc/ghci_history, although depending on your machine, it could be at a different place.

Comment: I don't seem to have a hidden .ghc under my home directory. Do I have to setup Prelude to make it record my commands?

Comment: What OS are you using?  I actually found the file in question by typing something large and unique in ghci, then doing a grep for that word at the command line....  You could also do a "locate ghci_history", or even "find . | grep ghci_history" in your home directory.